# External Hard Drive erased and possibly corrupted after partition change on gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, external-hdd

I have a WD Elements external hard drive and I used it on my Windows to install Ubuntu 14.04. I then used gparted to bring back Windows and run a dual-boot, so I changed the external hard drive's format from Fat32 to ntfs. It did not result in any loss whatsoever. The next day, however, I plugged the same hard drive into my laptop and instead of saying "WD Elements" when I open it, the drive said "160 GB Volume" and it was completely empty.
How, exactly, am I supposed to bring back the files on it? If I cannot do it manually, will a data engineer be able to do the same? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think you can format a partition and not loose data? See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 0):

Format is the action of either wiping a drive(quick method) or removing the partition table altogether to place another partition table on the drive specified.  The data you seek to recover is fragmented and will not be recoverable at the point your asking.  Also, the Disk is not corrupted.  However, if the disk did have errors that were non-recoverable using a disk repair tool, then the chances of further damage to any drive is greatly increased due to what is done on the drive its self.

I do recommended next time you back up your data before switching Operating System or even dual booting a second OS to prevent little mistakes like this one.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Should I seek professional advice?